# Which banks in mainland China (if any) don't charge ATM withdrawal fees

Tags: money, china, atms

What are some banks in China whose ATMs don't charge ATM withdrawal fees if I withdraw money from a foreign VISA or MasterCard? (If all of them charge these fees, which ones charge the least?)

(Or am I better off just taking USD and exchanging them in some currency exchange point? Assuming that my bank doesn't charge international withdrawal fees.)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your bank.

Some Chinese banks have agreements with international banks regarding this fee, but it is on a bank by bank basis. So the answer would be: ask your own bank.